# How to install LibUSB To use in a .cpp project using CLion IDE

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, libusb

How can I install and import libusb in a .cpp project I'm using the CLion 2022.3.3 IDE by JetBrains
My OS is a Windows 10 x64

I downloaded [libusb-win32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/files/libusb-win32-releases/1.2.7.3/) files but that didn't work.

the last thing i tried was to download this libusb file from [github libUSB-1.0.26](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases), then i put this file in the root directory of the project

this is my CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp usb.cpp libusb/libusb/libusb.h libusb/libusb/libusbi.h)
```

this is the files of project
[image]

Comment: Looks like you will have linker errors since you don't link the usb libraries.

Comment: BTW, Your question should show the errors and not leave that to the reader to figure out what is going on.

Comment: only error that show is that libary libUSB was not found